# Loop trough JSON file with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this part of a JSON file:

[image]

And the next record:

[image]

I need to get several fields from each record. For instance [City].

With this code I can get the first city:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($response, true);
echo $result['GetLocationsResult']['ResponseLocation'][0]['Address']['City'];
```

However I want to loop through all the records and get all [City] fields.

Comment: So what's the problem? It's a simple loop: `foreach($result['GetLocationsResult']['ResponseLocation'] as $location) { echo $location["Address"]["City"]; }`. Have you used `foreach` before?

Comment: BTW the JSON factor is largely irrelevant here - once you've decoded it, it's just a regular old PHP array, and you access the elements just like any other array.

Comment: Please copy the json into your question using the code formatting instead of posting pictures. Stackoverflow doesn't have OCR for this ;-)

Comment: I think I got distracted by the JSON factor, which I haven't done a lot with before. I get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be quite straight forward

```php
$locations = $result['GetLocationsResult']['ResponseLocation'];

$cities = [];
foreach($locations as $location)
{
   $cities[] = $location['Address']['City'];
}

var_dump($cities);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a more modern approach to getting all the cities, we don't need any loop anymore:

```
$cities = array_map(
    fn($location) => $location['Address']['City'],
    $result['GetLocationsResult']['ResponseLocation']
);

print_r($cities);
```

It depends on what exactly you need from the array whether this suits.

Answer (score 0):

The true param of the json_decode tells you that the decoded json is an associative array. Thus you can use it as an array an loop over the values you want as you would threat any other array.